# How to make multiple line text into a single line and add some commas

Tags: notepad++

i want to make a multiple line txt file (reading it on notepad++) into a single line texte with some commas. Example with the text

```
123
123
123
123

to:

123,123,123,123
```

Is it possible to do it with notepad++? if not, how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use find/replace.  Put yout line terminator in the find and , in the replace and replace all.  If you're on Windows, your line terminator is probably \r\n, but it could be \n or some other value.  You will need to set the mode to either extended or regex (regular expression).

Comment: thanks! i tried replacing only \n but it was changing the start of the texte line, didn't know about \r

Comment: :) so that worked for you?

Comment: it did, just waiting for StackOverflow to let me accept your answer haha, you were too fast

Comment: haha, I didn't even know you had to wait.

Comment: neither did i, when i tried it told me to wait 8 mins lol. Anyway, i just accepted your answer. Thanks a lot for answering me and being so fast at it!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in notepad++, I will write my solution in python programming language.

```
# You open the file
file = open("Location of the file right click on the text file and copy relative file.")
# You read the whole file and put it in a list where each line would be one 
# item in the list.
readFile = file.read().split("\n")
# Set a new variable so you can concatinate a string
text = ""
# Loop through the list of rows
for i in range(0, len(readFile), 1):
      # Concatinate the each row into one string and add a comma and a space.
     text = text + readFile[i] + ", "
# Print the text
print(text)
```

That is one way you can do this.

Comment: thanks for an alternative answer! i'll give it a try later.

Answer (score 1):

- Find what: `\R`
- Replace with: `,`

Where `\R` stands for any kind of linebreak (i.e. `\r`, `\n`, `\r\n`)